# Expand the function $\cos(\cos(x))$ into the Taylor series around $x = 0$ up to $o(x^6)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How to expand the function $\cos(\cos(x))$ into the Taylor series around $x = 0$ up to $o(x^6)$?
I got how to expand $\cos(x)$, but I don’t really see how to do $\cos(\cos(x))$.

Comment: Put the power series for $\cos$ into the power series for $\cos$ and calculate the terms up to the degree you need. Or calculate the first several derivatives, but that's much more tedious.

Comment: Expand $\cos(y)=a_0+a_1(y-1)+a_2(y-1)^2+\dots$ and let $y=\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\dots$

Comment: Or just set $f(x) = \cos(\cos x)$ and calculate the first six derivatives at $x = 0$, and write out the Taylor series. It is a little messy, but no more so than raising polynomials to powers.